# Psql not found in cmd Lauched through Java

Tags: java, postgresql, cmd

I know that this question looks a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296322/shp2pgsql-psql-command-not-found-through-processbuilder-java), but mine relates to Windows and in a crucial way. I have the following piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //String command = "\"psql --version\"";
    String psqlPath = "\"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\10\\bin\\psql.exe\"";
    String command = "\""+psqlPath+" --version \"";
    runPostgresqlTableCreator("start cmd.exe /k "+command);
}


private static void runPostgresqlTableCreator(String command) {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        try {
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This code works using psqlPath whereby it launches a cmd and prints the PostgresQL version as `psql (PostgreSQL) 10.7`. However, with using `psql --version`, it says *'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file*. Running `psql --version` on a cmd launched by me prints out the version as well. The environment variables are also set properly. From the link provided, the answer states that Java seems to have a problem recognizing the psql path from environment variables (though `String command = "\"java -version\""` displays the Java version).

For Linux, it is an okay thing to put the full path of `/usr/local/bin/psql`, because in most cases, this will always be the path. However, in Windows, users can decide to install PostgresQL in any directory and in any disk volume, making it difficult to get the full path to psql.exe. In my desktop application project using JavaFX, I need to run some psql commands but for something else and not version. I do not wish to set a place where clients can put the path to psql.exe on the interface.

My question is thus, is there a workaround to making psql work without using full path? (Please note that it is not the Postgresql version that I am interested in).

Answer (score 0):

You can use psql without using the full path every time by adding the full path to psql to your system variables. You can do this by going to the control panel, opening the Advanced system settings, clicking on "Environmental Variables" in system variables, and editing the environmental variables. Once this is done, psql can be referenced by simply typing "psql" as the path.

Note: do not delete the other variables. Add the path to psql to the list of environmental variables.

Here is a java document explaining adding to the path as well:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Once the environmental variable is set you can read it using the System.getenv(String name) method to access a specific variable. You can also use System.getenv() to return a map of all the environmental variables

System.getenv() JavaDoc:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--

Comment: I have the environment variables set. That's why doing ```psql --version``` on a cmd that I have launched myself returns the version. But it appears that Java is not able to read the path for psql.exe from the environment variables.

Comment: Oh I see. Then you should consider using System.getenv(). That command returns a map of the enviornmental variables which you can reference to access psql. Here is a java doc for System.getenv(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: I know this sounds weird but I have run the first piece of code in that link and it has printed out all the values for 'Path' variable (plus other variables) but ```C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin```, is missing. But if I look from the Control Panel ... > Environment Variables > System Variables and under Path = 'paths separated by semi-colons', it is there.

Comment: Perhaps try adding the path using `set variableName=value` or `setx variableName "Value"` to add it from cmd and see if that changes anything. Both methods are mentioned on this answer: https://superuser.com/a/284351